# How to block all traffic between two interfaces?

Tags: linux

Let's say I have two interfaces on one host, eth0 and eth1.  The behavior I'm seeing currently is:

Receive traffic on eth0, it finds a suitable route on eth1 and tries to send it.

I'm already intercepting the packets coming in on eth0 so I would like to stop this forwarding and drop all packets coming in on eth0 instead of sending them on eth1.

In essence, I'd like to block all traffic between two interfaces on one host.  Is this possible with iptables or routing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j DROP` should do what you’re requesting.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to control this at the kernel level with `sysctl`.  Setting the net.ipv4 and/or net.ipv6 forwarding values off.

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.forwarding = 0
```

Depending on the distribution you can configure this at startup by editing /etc/sysctl.conf or adding a file in /etc/sysctl.d.  Normally forwarding is disabled by default, so you may have a line enabling forwarding.

Some firewall builders will enable or disable forwarding depending on the configuration.

Comment: let's say, you want to block traffic from eth0 to eth2, but you want to allow traffic from eth0 to eth1. This approach doesn't work.